# Wanting to edit a google maps info bubble

Tags: google-maps

I have to edit an info bubble on a website to help someone out.
The site is already online and i dont have the ftp login details so i cant download the files and use them locally to test it.
So im having some issues with inserting a logo on the top of the bubble, like a header.
Im also having problems with the code needed to add 'to here' and 'from here' directions at the bottom of the bubble.
Everything else is plain text in the middle of these 2 objects, so thats easy.

Can anyone help me with the header pic and directions code?

Comment: Are you asking how to write KML?  Or how to add links to KML?  I kind of understand the question, but I'm not sure what you are trying to do.  You said you don't have the FTP login info -- does that mean that when done, you cannot actually implement your edits?  Sorry -- I am confused.

Comment: i will give the edited code to the guy who gave me the job and he will implement it, i must just make the changes, for me its kind of like a training exercise.
i need to take an existing bubble, add a logo and 'to here' 'from here' directions.

Answer (score 0):

I think this demo from google might be what you want:

```
http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/interactive/index.html#./Point_Placemarks/Point_Placemarks.Descriptive_HTML.kml.
```

It does not show actual images, but it shows how to put that kind of HTML in the bubbles.